# VB.net Compile Time Error

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem while compiling one of my projects in vb.net. I have a solution consisting of multiple project,one of which is the exe. Now when i am trying to compile that project i get an error which states

"Error    140 Invalid argument. Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"

Can anyone please help me.
Thankx in advance

Comment: Can you post the code that's generating this error. Not the whole project but just the line and the few lines around it so we can see the context.

Comment: I think none of my code generated the error because I have a separate copy of the same project which has the same code, but its running fine.

Comment: ... do you have a parameter/variable/ANYTHING called "length"?

Comment: Post your code so someone can help you

Comment: I cannot copy any code because,while compiling when the errir is shown in the error list,nothing is there in the (file/line/column) cells.Only in the project cell, the name of the project is given

Comment: Sounds like you have something strange in your project's compile options, like perhaps a pre- or post-build command or an undefined custom constant.

Answer (score 0):

To help find the error/which project it is in, you should try building each project separately, starting at the one lowest in your dependency tree and moving towards your exe (assuming this makes sense).  This should help you find which project has the problem.

In visual studio you should be able to right click on a project in the solution explorer and tell it to build/rebuild just that one.  Also, doing a full clean on the solution (right click the solution and select "Clean Solution") works wonders sometimes.